# Terse error-checking in Python

Tags: python, assert

I often want have my Python code die if some condition isn't satisfied. I usually just use `assert whatever()`. However, I sometimes run with `__debug__` equal to `False`. In these cases, there are still some assert-like conditions that I want to check for. I believe the "right" way to handle these cases is just a regular if: `if not whatever(): raise Exception('Error message!')`. In other words, I believe it's only correct to use assert for checks that you'd be happy to do without, presumably those that are time-consuming or that will be run many times. Is there a terser way to accomplish the same thing as the full conditional?

In Perl I would just use `whatever() or die`. Of course, given the philosophical differences between the languages it's hardly a surprise to see Perl require fewer characters.

Comment: What's wrong with `def die(why): raise Exception(why)`?  Then use it as `whatever() or die('whatever is broken')`

Comment: So, you still want your code to die even when you have __ debug __ = False? If so, you could do sys.exit() if the conditional is met (or not met, depending on what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is to create your own version of assert:

```
def confirm(expression):
    if not expression:
        raise AssertionError
```

Then, instead of using `assert whatever()`, you could instead do `confirm(whatever())`.

Alternatively, if you want to emulate perl, you could do the following:

```
def die():
    raise Exception()

whatever() or die()
```

If `whatever()` returns `True`, `die()` will never execute (due to boolean short-circuiting), and the program will merrily chug away. If `whatever()` returns `False`, then the program will terminate.

Technically, this is two more characters then perl, but you could rename `die` to `d`, and end up writing the same amount of characters.

I'm pretty sure that this isn't a Pythonic way of doing things, but the option is available, if you prefer it that way.